# .spacemacs configuration file FAIL: with-eval-after-load

Tags: emacs, configuration-files, org-mode, spacemacs

I am new to emacs and this is my first attempt at editing the .spacemacs configuration file.
I am attempting to install Org layer on Spacemacs but got a warning.

org is wrapped in with-eval-after-load, as recommended in http://spacemacs.org/layers/+emacs/org/README.html#important-note

This is from my ~/.spacemacs file, with org wrapped in with-eval-after-load:

```
 dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
   '(
     markdown
     ;; ----------------------------------------------------------------
     ;; Example of useful layers you may want to use right away.
     ;; Uncomment some layer names and press <SPC f e R> (Vim style) or
     ;; <M-m f e R> (Emacs style) to install them.
     ;; ----------------------------------------------------------------
     helm
     ;; auto-completion
     ;; better-defaults
     emacs-lisp
     ;; git
     ;; markdown
     (with-eval-after-load 'org
       org
       )
     ;; (shell :variables
     ;;        shell-default-height 30
     ;;        shell-default-position 'bottom)
     spell-checking
```

When I dotspacemacs/sync-configuration-layers and this warning comes up:

```
warning: (Spacemacs) some tests failed, check `*dotfile-test-results*' buffer
```

Here is the screen shot from dotfile-test-results buffer with "FAIL: with-eval-after-load":
[image]

What could be causing the warning?
I am using GNU Emacs 25.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `(with-eval-after-load 'org org)` and replace it with a plain `org`.

That isn't where they intended you to put that.

If you find yourself writing (or copying) *custom* org-mode configuration code, then use the suggested approach.